# What is a reliable way to find which config file mongodb is currently using?

Tags: mongodb, config

If mongod is currently running, what is one (or multiple) ways to lookup the path of the config file it followed on launch (if any)?

I would like a reliable method that covers various operating systems.  It is okay to have a different method per OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/#dbcmd.getCmdLineOpts), running the following two commands in the mongo shell:

```js
use admin
db.runCommand({ getCmdLineOpts: 1 })
```

should give you an output like this, which is blatantly copied:

```js
{
    "argv" : [
           "/usr/bin/mongod",
           "--config",
           "/etc/mongod.conf",
           "--fork"
    ],
    "parsed" : {
           "bind_ip" : "127.0.0.1",
           "config" : "/etc/mongodb/mongodb.conf",
           "dbpath" : "/srv/mongodb",
           "fork" : true,
           "logappend" : "true",
           "logpath" : "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log",
           "quiet" : "true"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: When I run this in the mongo shell, I get the output `{
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "getCmdLineOpts may only be run against the admin database.",
    "code": 13
}`.  And if I run `show dbs`, there is no database named `admin`.

Comment: @mareoraft Nevermind. Simply put a "user admin" before the command. Databases and  collections are implicit in MongoDB.

Comment: It seems you meant `use admin`.  I edited your answer and have accepted it, since indeed this should work on all platforms!

Comment: @mareoraft Thanks a lot. Of course, that was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on all n*x systems, as far as I know:

```
ps aux | grep mongo
```

The output should include something like:

```
mongodb         627  0.0  1.9 1203228  9544  -  I    19Jun15   1728:28.03 /usr/local/bin/mongod --logpath /var/db/mongodb/mongod.log --logappend --config /usr/local/etc/mongodb.conf --dbpath /var/db/mongodb
```

Note that the `mongod` command was launched with the option `--config` and the value `/usr/local/etc/mongodb.conf`, which is the desired path.